# Converting raw text to JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to implement a parser which converts raw text data into JSON format . The text will given as follows .

(An example)

- # Menu Name
- ## Section Name
- ### Item Name
- > Description
- > Price
- > Image URL (optional)
- ### Item Name 2
- > Description
- > Price
- > Image URL (optional)

The order of elements will in the given order .

The desired output which i want is as follows :

```
{
 name: "menu name",
 sections: [
  {
     name: "Section name",
     items: [{
        name: "item name",
        description: "description",
        price: 23.00
     },
     {
        name: "item name",
        description: "description",
        price: 43.00
     },
    ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Note : There can be multiple items in each section and each menu can have multiple sections .So the order should be maintained i.e If a new section comes up the items below that should now be a part of that section .

I tried a solution using String parsing and it is working fine but i wanted to know a standard method of performing this task .

Comment: There is no *standard* way to parse a *custom* text format.

Comment: You could write your own function where you create a json in string format and as soon as you are done you can just parse it to JSON.

Comment: Have you done anything already? lets see it. from your raw text I see a pattern, if the pattern is constant, maybe there might be some way.

Comment: You can use a PEG, something like [pegjs](https://pegjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the expected output is JSON, it might make sense to use a JSON-oriented tool such as [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).  There are of course many different possible approaches, but here is one that is simple, direct, easily extensible, and in some ways easy to understand, at least for those familiar with a JSON query language.

The program below will produce one JSON object for each "menu" (i.e., each occurrence of a "# Menu  Name" line).

### menus.jq

```
# The next key name in an item
def keyname:
  if (.description | not) then "description"
  elif (.price | not) then "price"
  elif (.url | not) then "url"
  else length|tostring
  end;

def menu_name($s):
  . += [{name: $s}];
def section_name($s):
  .[-1].sections += [{name: $s}];
def item_name($s):
  .[-1].sections[-1].items += [{name: $s}];
def item_description($s):
  (.[-1].sections[-1].items[-1]|keyname) as $key
  | .[-1].sections[-1].items[-1][$key] = $s;

reduce inputs as $in ([];
  if $in|test("^ *$") then .       # ignore blank lines
  else ($in|split(" ")) as $tokens
  | ($in|sub("[^ ]* *";"")) as $phrase
  | if $tokens[0] == "#"     then menu_name( $phrase )
    elif $tokens[0] == "##"  then section_name( $phrase )
    elif $tokens[0] == "###" then item_name( $phrase )
    elif $tokens[0] == ">"   then item_description( $phrase )
    else .
    end
  end )
| .[]  # stream the menus
```

### Invocation

The above uses `inputs` and so the `-n` command-line option is critical:

```
jq -n -f menus.jq input.txt
```

### Output

With the sample input:

```
{
  "name": "Menu Name",
  "sections": [
    {
      "name": "Section Name",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item Name",
          "description": "Description",
          "price": "Price",
          "url": "Image URL (optional)"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item Name 2",
          "description": "Description",
          "price": "Price",
          "url": "Image URL (optional)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```